# We have a cultureinfo class in . net , do we have a similar kind of structure/package in node js?

Tags: node.js

I have a current locale, for eg. `zh-CNS-HK`
For eg.

```js
cultureString = "zh-CNS-HK";
var cultureObject = new CultureInfo(cultureString); ***// culture object to specific locale***
```

We have few properties in `cultureObject` which are like neutral culture and specific culture.
So if I need specific culture i will get like `cultureObject.name = "zh-HK"` instead of `zh-CNS-HK`.

How can I get the same thing(`zh-HK`) in node js? and how can I check whether it is a neutral culture or specific culture?

Note: `Currentlocale` I am extracting it from the windows registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparable object in Node.js (and JavaScript) is probably the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object.

This allows you to get Date / Time formats etc.

You could use the Locale region property to determine if it is a specific or neutral locale,

To understand the locale formats, I would take a look at the BCP 47 standard (https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)

e.g.

```js
const date = new Date("2020-05-14T05:30:00Z");
let locale = "zh-HK";
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale);
console.log("Formatted date:", formatter.format(date));

console.log("locale region (zh-HK):", new Intl.Locale("zh-HK").region);

console.log("locale region (zh):", new Intl.Locale("zh").region);

function isSpecificLocale(locale) {
    return (!!locale.region);
}

console.log("IsSpecificLocale (zh-HK):", isSpecificLocale(new Intl.Locale("zh-HK")));
console.log("IsSpecificLocale (zh):", isSpecificLocale(new Intl.Locale("zh")));
```

Comment: Is there any way to filter  locale like "zh-CNS-HK" to "zh-HK"  based on specific locale/region?

Comment: Well, as long as the locale identifier (zh-CNS-HK) conforms to BCP 47 locale identifier standards (it should!), we know the middle section is the script, so you could simply omit this section. The Locale object gives you a language code and a region. Combining these should give you a language-region locale. For some reason the Locale constructor doesn't like the CNS script identifier however!